# How can i make this list horizontal with equal widths?

Tags: html, css

I just dont know how I can make this into a horizontal list where all elements are equal width.

I dont really know if there is any information missing so just comment/message if you need any more information. All the CSS which isn't in the “grid” `<li>` is for a navbar.

```css
 body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
    }

    .intro{
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
    }

    .active {
    background-color: red;
    }
    ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    }

    li {
    float: right;
    }

    li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
    }

    li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    background-color: #D3D3D3
    }

 


    .button {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #555555;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    .button:hover {
    background-color: #555555;
    color: white;
    }



    li.grid{
    float:left
    width: 25%
    }
```

```html
<ul>

    <li class="grid">
    <form action="http://google.com">
    <button class="button" type="submit"  />
    Computers, printers, mobile phones and the widgets that accompany them    account for the emission of about two per cent of the estimated total of emissions from human activity. And that is the same as the aviation industry&#8217;s contribution. 25 per cent of the emissions in question are generated by the manufacture of computers. The rest come from their use.
    <br>
    <br>
    </button>
    </form>
    </li>

    <li  class="grid">
    <form action="http://google.com" style="float: left">
    <button class="button" type="submit"  />
    Computers can be used to reduce emissions produced by other industries, up to 7.8 billion tonnes by 2020, or five times ICT&#8217;s own footprint. Computers can make industries more efficient and less wasteful of power and fuel.
    </button>
    </form>
    </li>

    <li   class="grid">
    <form action="http://google.com" style="float: left">
    <button class="button" type="submit"  />
    The use of computers has led to both positive and negative impacts on the climate change of our planet. Computers can help make some processes more efficient and save energy while the use and manufacture of computers contributes to the increased use of energy which leads to global warming. This website helps you to look at the positives and negatives of computing and climate change.</p>

    </button>
    </form>
    </li>

    <li   class="grid">
    <form action="http://google.com" style="float: left">
    <button class="button" type="submit"  />
    There are many ways in which computers can help cut down on our use of energy. Computers are steadily improving the amount of energy that they use with the smaller computers producing less CO2 than larger desktop computers.
    <br>
    <br>
    </button>
    </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You forgot the semi-colons in `li.grid`. Questions that are just typos are usually closed but you can also just remove this question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution is to use flex box:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
}

li {
 width: 25%
}
```

the style of "flex" on tha parent automatically effects the display for its children.

you can read more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)